# Issue in the code while writting variables dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.6, php-7.1

I have written below lines of code

```
          $advsr_firstname="David"
          $advsr_middlename ="";
         // note that these two are passed through function parametre



             $first_name=array('$or' => array(array("student.first_name" => new MongoRegex("/$advsr_firstname/i"))));
          $last_name= array('$or' => array(array("student.last_name" => new MongoRegex("/$advsr_middlename/i"))));

          $keyarguments = array(
                'first_name=>advsr_firstname',
                'last_name=>advsr_middlename'
                );

              $empty = "X9w+";

              foreach ($keyarguments as $key => $value)
               {

                if(${$value} =='' || ${$value} =='0' || ${$value} =="Select")
                {
                   ${$key} = array('$or' => array(array("dummy_feild" => new MongoRegex("/$empty/i"))));
                }
              }      

            $orrollno= array('$or' => array(array("student.roll_no" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));    

            $query = array( '$or' => array($first_name,$last_name,$orrollno));
```

I am trying to write query dynamically so that `$query` will work properly.

I want that if "$advsr_middlename" is empty then the code should dynamically modify the expression $last_name in the loop like

```
    $last_name = array('$or' => array(array("dummy_feild" => new MongoRegex("/$empty/i"))));
```

It is throwing error messages undefined variable first_name=>advsr_firstname
....

Please help me as the code is not working!!!

Comment: it looks like `$keyarguments` is incorrectly written. The key and value should be quoted rather than quotes around the entire entry

Comment: Why you did not indent your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be the solution: fix the syntax of `$keyarguments` array from

```
      $keyarguments = array(
            'first_name=>advsr_firstname',
            'last_name=>advsr_middlename'
            );
```

to

```
$keyarguments = [
    'first_name' => 'advsr_firstname',
    'last_name' => 'advsr_middlename',
];
```